# Convert two 2D lists to a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to convert the following two 2D lists to a list of dictionaries like:

```
list1 = [ ['name', 'age', 'birth'], ['name', 'age', 'birth'] ]

list2 = [ ['a', 20, 2000], ['b', 23, 2003] ]
```

and I want the result like this:

```
list3 = [ {'name' : 'a',
           'age' : 20,
           'birth' : 2000
          },
          {'name' : 'b',
           'age' : 23,
           'birth' : 2003}]
```

I tried using `zip` to convert but I couldn't get the result.

Comment: *"I tried using zip to convert but I couldn't get the result"* - Please show what you tried so we can help you get it right...

Comment: Also can you explain why there is even a need for `list1`? It seems like it could be a simple list as both sub-lists are the same

Answer (score 1):

What you need here is nested-`zip`ping. First `zip` the header list with the data list, then `zip` each header with its value:

```py
list3 = []
for header_list, data_list in zip(list1, list2):
    d = {}
    for header, value in zip(header_list, data_list):
        d[header] = value
    list3.append(d)
    
print(list3)
```

Which gives:

```
[{'name': 'a', 'age': 20, 'birth': 2000}, {'name': 'b', 'age': 23, 'birth': 2003}]
```

This can be a bit reduced by using the [dict constructor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict):

```py
list3 = []
for header_list, data_list in zip(list1, list2):
    list3.append(dict(zip(header_list, data_list)))
```

---

It can also be further reduced to a less-advisable, less-readable list-comprehension:

```
list3 = [dict(zip(header_list, data_list)) for header_list, data_list in zip(list1, list2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use index correspondancy between lists.

```
list1 = [ ["name", "age", "birth"], ["name", "age", "birth"] ]
list2 = [ ["a", 20, 2000], ["b", 23, 2003] ]

list3 = []

for i in range(len(list1)):
    dico = {}
    for j in range(len(list1[i])):
        dico[list1[i][j]] = list2[i][j]
    list3.append(dico)

print(list3)
```

OUTPUT:

```
[{'name': 'a', 'age': 20, 'birth': 2000}, {'name': 'b', 'age': 23, 'birth': 2003}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
list1 = [ ['name', 'age', 'birth'], ['name', 'age', 'birth'] ]

list2 = [ ['a', 20, 2000], ['b', 23, 2003] ]

list3 = []

for l1,l2 in zip(list1,list2):
    ###### Dictionary Comphrehension
    list3 += [{ k:v for k,v in zip(l1,l2)}] 

list3
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one-liner, which uses a dictionary comprehension and `zip` applied to the elements from the overall zip of the two lists:

```
[{k:v for k,v in zip(*zipped)} for zipped in zip(list1,list2)]
```

**On Edit**

As per the Tomerikoo's comment, this can be improved further to:

```
[dict(zip(*zipped)) for zipped in zip(list1,list2)]
```

Comment: The structure `{k: v for k,v in zip(...)}` can be reduced with the dict constructor: `dict(zip(...))` :)

Comment: @Tomerikoo Good point. I'll add it. Python can be remarkably concise.